# Silverlight/WP7 Animation was skipped

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have the problem when I start a new animation after a storyboards finished, this animation is not shown. The target property jumps directly to the end position defined in the animation.

My setup is:

1. Create a storyboard once
2. Start the first animation
3. storyboard calls complete event
4. Start the next animation

Both animations have the same target properties and the same storyboard.

I have those animation jumps in other cases too, but they are random.

Comment: Can you show the timings or XAML? Startup delays are the biggest cause of lost animation as it takes the starttime from when Storyboard.Begin() is triggered, rather than when it gets its act together. Do you have very short animations?

Comment: The begin time is 0 and the duration 1 sec, same for the storyboard. I set it manually to 0 and the animations are run fine about 3 times, then the second one starts to fail

Comment: It seems, that the problem was caused by using the storyboard.Stop() function. Now it is okay. Hmmm I'm not sure if it gone forever. But thanks for the tipp with the timing, it helped

Comment: You are better off re-using storyboards and not calling stop until all storyboards are finished. They hold the final values that way until a subsequent storyboard changes them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Startup delays are the biggest cause of lost animation as it takes the start time from when Storyboard.Begin() is triggered, rather than when it gets its act together. This is a problem for very short animations.

A second issue is calling `Stop()` on a storyboard. That resets any changed values back to the start values (as Storyboard animation only does temporary updates on Dependency Properties). If you are running several Storyboards in sequence, do not call stop on any until the last one finishes.